# Organizing configuration file and variables

Tags: python, import, configuration

I would like to create configuration files for a project, in an efficient way
to facilitate both coder's development and user's customization.

I have a configuration module named `projectConf`, which holds different classes, each of them having configuration attributes:

```
class Config1:
    C_1_1 = "string"
    C_1_2 = ["string1", "string2"]
    C_1_3 = 4

class Config2:
    C_2_1 = "another string"
    C_2_2 = 10
```

I could put attributes in nice dictionnaries indeed, but I use classes to hold my data for development convenience. Indeed, with any decent IDE, I can import the desired class and make use of the autocompletion feature to directly see which fields are available. 
I presently use Pycharm. I am quite content with it and I don't know of any IDE autocompleting dict keys. But this is preference matters, it would be nice to target most common IDE and to find a generic solution.

My attributes hold default configuration. But those have to be rendered available for any user in a text configuration file. So my next step is to get all of the classes' attributes.

In the same module `projectConf` I implemented the following method to print each classes' attribute:

```
import sys, inspect
def printClassFields():
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isclass):
        print "\nName: ", name, "\tObj: ", obj
        for field in getClassVariables(name):
            value = getClassField(name, field)
            msg = field + " = " + ", ".join(value) if isinstance(value, list) else field + " = " + str(getClassField(name, field))
            print "  " + msg
```

So I am using `sys.module[__name__]`. I can use this method to write a basic configuration file. The thing is, ideally, it would be nice to have a module separated from the configuration file, which will do the writing of any file configuration module such as `projectConf`. So I wrote the module `configWriter` containing the class `ClassAttributesReader`:

```
import sys, inspect
class ClassAttributesReader:

    def __init__(self, moduleName):
        self._moduleName = moduleName
        if moduleName:
            print "[Reading module] ", moduleName

    def printClassFields(self):
        for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(self._moduleName, inspect.isclass):
            print "\nName: ", name, "\tObj: ", obj
            for field in self.getClassVariables(name):
                value = self.getClassField(name, field)
                msg = field + " = " + ", ".join(value) if isinstance(value, list) else field + " = "\
                                    + str(self.getClassField(name, field))
                print "  " + msg

    def getClassField(self, className, variableName):
        """
        Retrieves the value of a class variable.
        :param className:
        :param variableName:
        :return:
        """
        try:
            return eval(str(className) + "." + str(variableName))
            # print className + "." + variableName + " = " + eval(str(className) + "." + str(variableName))
        except NameError as ne:
            print "ERROR: " + ne.message

    def evalContent(self, content):
        eval(content)
```

And I call `ClassAttributesReader` from `projectConf` this way:

```
import sys
class Config1:
    C_1_1 = "string"
    C_1_2 = ["string1", "string2"]
    C_1_3 = 4

class Config2:
    C_2_1 = "another string"
    C_2_2 = 10


def main(argv=None):
    from configWriter import ClassAttributesReader
    car = ClassAttributesReader(sys.modules[__name__])
    car.printClassFields()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

The problem here is that the class `ClassAttributesReader` needs the import of the configuration file module such as `projectConf`. I don't know how to do that  properly,  I tried using `eval` in the `ClassAttributeReader` to dynamically make the import:

```
 def evalContent(self, content):
        eval(content)
```

alas without success. I don't know how to do it. So at this point I am considering converting all the classes attributes from the configuration module and turn them into dictionnaries, which will be passed to the `ClassAttributeReader`. This way would circumvent the import issue, and maybe 
and it may be less error prone? But this converting method would require the same kind of code than the method `printClassFields` with `sys.module[__name__]`. If I want to put this method in `ClassAttributeReader` I would still have to deal with dynamic imports.

So I would like to know if there are better ways to tackle this issue, be it putting configuration attributes in class variables for autocompletion purpose. Eventually if my solution does not seem half bad, I need a way to make dynamic imports.

What's your take?

---

### EDIT 1

Just to draw your attention on the fact that, I am aware of the argparse module, and I intend to use it in order to read attributes from the configuration file. My question here is different. I want a way to generate that configuration file for the user, from the hard coded attributes in my configuration classes as shown above. So the user can see the default hard coded attributes in this newly generated configuration file, and then change those attributes if needed. My program will then update those values according to the users', at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I see where you are going with this, but you should stop.  The problem is, you don't want to ever 'execute' the configuration file because so many random things could wind up in there and cause you problems.  Its better to use INI or JSON files.  Load the files into dicts and use the dicts directly or populate a configuration object with the values from the dicts.

See the configparser:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Comment: You mean it's ok to keep my classes and attributes, and that they should be initialized with a .ini file? Or also to get rid of those class attributes?

Comment: Yeah, you can use objects to store your configuration, just use one of these libraries to read a json or ini file into a dict.  You can even have a method to load the file like this:

class MyConfigurationClass(object):
    def __init__(config_file = None):
         if config_file:
                config_dict = load_ini_config_file(config_file)

         self.setting1 = config_dict.get("setting1", setting1_default)

Comment: Thanks, my concern is not about reading configuration file, but about generating it from the default hard coded attributes in my classes. Then once it has been generated, I will of course parse it to update the hard-coded attributes, at run-time.

Comment: Yeah, in that case, you just have to build a dict of all of your configuration variables and use the libraries to dump it out as JSON or INI.